# Citations Show up in the bibliography but not in the text

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the style guide provided by my university and am trying to place a bibliography at the end of each chapter.  I am using the `chapterbib` package and doing:

```
latex main.tex
bibtex each_chapter.aux
latex main.tex
latex main.tex
```

All the .blg and .bbl files are created.  Also, the call `\bibliography{bibtex_file}` is at the end of each chapter.

The issue is that even though each chapter has a reference list at the end, fully populated, the locations in the text where `\cite{}` occurs are still [?].  What could cause this?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete, small document we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem. Since it obviously does work - that being the point of the package - we can't guess why it isn't working without seeing the problematic code.

Comment: Make sure you are using `\include{}` for the chapters. And that each one includes `\bibliography{}` and `\bibliographystyle{}`.